# Case sensitive search in Django, but ignored in Mysql

Tags: mysql, django, collation

I have a field in a Django Model for storing a unique (hash) value. Turns out that the database (MySQL/inno) doesn't do a case sensitive search on this type (VARCHAR), not even if I explicitly tell Django to do a case sensitive search `Document.objects.get(hash__exact="abcd123")`. So "abcd123" and "ABcd123" are both returned, which I don't want.

```
class document(models.Model):
   filename    = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   hash        = models.CharField(max_length=33 )
```

I can change the 'hash field' to a BinaryField , so in the DB it becomes a LONGBLOB , and it does do a case-sensitive search (and works). However, this doesn't seem very efficient to me. 
Is there a better way (in Django) to do this, like adding 'utf8 COLLATE'? or what would be the correct Fieldtype in this situation? 
(yes, I know I could use PostgreSQL instead..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dan-klasson mentioned, the [default non-binary string comparison is case insensetive by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html); notice the `_ci` at the end of `latin1_swedish_ci`, it stands for case-insensetive.
You can, as Dan mentioned, create the database with a case sensitive collation and character set.

You may be also interested to know that you can always [create a single table or even set only a single column to use a different collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) (for the same result). And you may also change these collations post creation, for instance per table:

```
ALTER TABLE documents__document CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Additionally, if you rather not change the database/table charset/collation, Django allows to [run a custom query using the raw method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries). So you may be able to work around the change by using something like the following, though I have not tested this myself:

```
Document.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM documents__document LIKE '%s' COLLATE latin1_bin", ['abcd123'])
```

Answer (score 4):

The default collation for character set for MySQL is latin1_swedish_ci, which is case insensitive. Not sure why that is. But you should create your database like so:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: I've changed the database now, but I was hoping this could be done inside Django. but this works too.

Comment: You really ought to always use utf8. You're bound to run into problems if you don't.