# Does Django's 'exact' field lookup perform a case-insensitive search?

Tags: django

From what I read on the Django manual, I thought that the `exact` field lookup would perform a case-SENSITIVE search, yet, when I do this

`FormZBaseElementExtraLabel.objects.filter(label__exact='his6')`

I get the following output

`<QuerySet [<FormZBaseElementExtraLabel: HIS6>]>`

clearly not case-sensitive, and in fact identical to the default `filter`  or `iexact`.

Any ideas as to what could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect that you are using MySQL with a default collation which is case insensitive. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073941/case-sensitive-search-in-django-but-ignored-in-mysql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all for the answers. Indeed, I've realized that I use MySQL (MariaDB) with collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, which explains why the `exact` query lookup works case-insensitively.

Without changing the collation of the underlying database (or some of its columns specifically), as pointed out, the following search is case-sensitive `FormZBaseElementExtraLabel.objects.filter(label__contains = 'his6').filter(label = 'his6')`. Alternatively, one could run a custom query using the raw method as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073941/case-sensitive-search-in-django-but-ignored-in-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

Actually __exact is for Exact match

And __iexact is for Case-insensitive exact match

for more info you can visit the django documentation [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/) page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
To case-SENSITIVE search

```
FormZBaseElementExtraLabel.objects.filter(**{'label__contains': 'his6'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this one which utilizes [BINARY expr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) for MySQL string case-sensitive match:

```
from django.db.models.fields import Field
from django.db.models import Lookup

@Field.register_lookup
class StrExact(Lookup):
    """
    MySQL string case sensitive string lookup
    """

    lookup_name = 'str_exact'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "%s = binary %s" % (lhs, rhs), params
```

Usage:

```
FormZBaseElementExtraLabel.objects.filter(label__str_exact='his6').count()
```

Read more about Custom Lookup https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-lookups/